# array_walk and anonymous function

Tags: php, arrays, anonymous-function

I'm trying to apply `ucfirst` to the words in an array using `array_walk` and an anonymous function. I want to change the values of the "original" array `$fruits`. Since I can't use pass by reference, what can you recommend me to achieve that?

```
<?php

$fruits = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry');

array_walk($fruits, function($a) {
        $fruits = ucfirst($a);
});

var_dump($fruits);

//results

array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1] =>
  string(6) "orange"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "banana"
  [3] =>
  string(6) "cherry"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_walk(
    $fruits, 
    function(&$a) {
        $a = ucfirst($a);
    }
);
```

Comment: What is &$a in this case? Is it a reference to $fruits?

Comment: No, &$a is a reference to an individual entry in the $fruits array

Answer (score 6):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is a better function in this situation.

```
$fruits = array_map('ucfirst', $fruits);
```

Comment: @str: I thought you could directly pass function names in newer PHP versions, but it does not seem to be possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the foreach loop:

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry');

foreach($fruits as $key => $value)
{
    $fruits[$key] = ucfirst($value);
}
```

Comment: He's walking for a reason. I think he would know foreach :)

Comment: @DaveChen true :) I think I prefer Felix Klings answer as well! However, for anyone stumbling upon this post, maybe mine will come in useful for those!

Answer (score 0):

```
$allUpperCase = array_map(function($fruit){
    return ucfirst($fruit);
}, $fruits);
```